# Robot anime of the 80s

Tags: story-identification, anime

I am desperately trying to remember an anime I used to watch as a kid in the 80s.

It was about robots, I don't remember if the boy (the protagonist) could transform into a robot or he just was the pilot but the weird thing was that before starting the "robot action" a group of girls "prepared" this guy bathing and scrubbing him (the whole scene lasted a few seconds).

I am not totally sure but I think I remember that the boy looked more mature after the girls' treatment

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: When Wataru Toki turns into Yattodetaman (superhero AND robot pilot), some girls from the future help him wear the super suit, unfortunately I don't remember if they bathed him and I can't find the full scene, only these shots: http://timebokanturnip.tumblr.com/post/135697495941/yattodetaman-character-biography-wataru-toki  If it rings a bell, I'll turn it into a full answer

Comment: Hello, yes, it's that. I solved yesterday by myself and I forgot to edit here. Thanks anyway. Mine was a "false memory", there is no bath, just the girls helping him, and it happens just in one episode (44th), you can find the whole episode on youtube. thanks again

Comment: @Guy78 ok! I expanded the comment into a full answer, you can accept it if you like it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(expanded from the comment)

### It is ***Yattodetaman***, [one of the Time Bokan Series (see this other question)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/160125/an-anime-i-watched-in-the-80s-i-was-too-young-to-remember-the-name/).

When Wataru Toki turns into Yattodetaman (superhero AND robot pilot), [some girls from the future help him wear the super suit](http://timebokanturnip.tumblr.com/post/135697495941/yattodetaman-character-biography-wataru-toki). 
Wimpy and coward before the "treatment", he is definitely more "mature" (stronger and brave) after the transformation - this is also due to the hammer to the head, super food and super fast training. The whole transformation happens inside a time-slowing beam, so it takes only 3 seconds of "real time".

[image: Yattodetaman transformation]

As you said in the comment, part of the transformation is visible in episode 44, but the **very first episode** in which the full transformation sequence appears is **episode 29** (here in Italian):

The girls appear again in **episode 40** (in which all characters play themselves on stage). In this case the girls undress him *completely*, but they don't bathe him, they just dress him as Yattodetaman.

Comment: I have seen plenty of odd and unusual cartoons/anime but this is ridiculous.  I love it!